# HTML5 Canvas: Is there a way to convert stroke (and its width and caps) to path?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

What I need to do is to create bezier curve with dynamic stroke width, say 10 pixels, and with round line caps. I want it to be a path for further more-complex filling procedures.

I have tried following which does not work:

```
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.lineCap = 'round';
context.moveTo(10, 10);
context.quadraticCurveTo(10, 100, 200, 200);
context.save();
context.clip();
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
context.restore();
```

It makes the path look like this (Image 1):

[image: Image 1]

The problem is that it closes the path (from 10, 10 to 200, 200) with straight line and, furthermore it does not care about stroke width nor about line caps. But I would need only the bezier curve with its stroke width and line caps to be noted and without closing the path with straight line.

I want the path to look like this (Image 2):

[image: Image2]

I can draw it with the code below:

```
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = 'red';
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.lineCap = 'round';
context.moveTo(10, 10);
context.quadraticCurveTo(10, 100, 200, 200);
context.stroke();
```

Except the code above draws it as a stroke. Can I export the result to path for further work?

Comment: The canvas API mostly provides a way to color in pixels on the canvas. Once you've drawn something, that's all you have - pixels.

Comment: *...further more-complex filling procedures* and *...export the result to path for further work?*. Not exactly sure what you're asking. You can both stroke and fill a single path. That would give you both an inside fill and an outside stroke and stroke / fill could have separate color styles. But if you want multiple fillStyles then you must create multiple paths -- you only get 1 fillStyle per beginPath.

Comment: Your question does not make any sense (at least to me).  In your first example you are creating a clip path and clipping a red rectangle.  Clips can't have strokes.  But in your second example you are creating a path and stroking it supposedly how you want.  But you claim that it isn't what you want because it isn't a "path".  I assure you it definitely *is* a path.  Perhaps you have your terminology confused?

Comment: Look, I want to create a path which would be an outline of the bezier stroke including its line width and line cap. It is gonna be used for clipping. When I draw a bezier it does not care about line width used when I use it as a path for clipping. In other words, I want the whole stroke to be converted to fill area. Can I do that? Perhaps not.

Comment: Okay, my solution was to calculate the bounding shape of a curve stroke (taking account its weight) and create a fill.

Comment: @Nerva How did you come about calculating the stroke? I'd love to know how you did this!